# Can't load angular or CSS file on Digital Ocean

Tags: html

I am completely new to Digital Ocean. I have a Ubuntu droplet set up on digital ocean and am able to access my index.html file on port 80. My app is set up as a single page application using angular routing.

It loads the navbar and seems to be loading bootstrap...but both angular and my own css file are not loading. I initially thought it was a problem with my bower installing angular dependencies, but even just my local css file is not being attached. My css file is included with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
```

For some reason bootstrap seems to be working though:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Any tips or suggestions on what the problem might be? I'm completely lost.

Comment: what messages appear in the console in the web inspector?

Comment: try going to the stylesheet it self to see if you didn't specfic the url incorrectly. so if your running it on example.com/page/ , the the css will be example.com/page/css/style.css . Please note that your url is a relative url, not absolute url

Comment: the only message in the console web inspector is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: for the absolute url should i be using the ip address that correlates to my droplet?

Comment: if the address to the stylesheet is : "http://example.com/css/style.css", then the absolute address is "/css/style.css"

Answer (score 0):

The hrefs in all your links are set up to work in your local environment, but not on digital ocean.  Bootstrap works because you are linking to an external url on a CDN.

You'll have to work through all the relative links in your hrefs. There are numerous approaches to this, including embedding the entire server path.

I'm not certain but it might be enough to replace  href="css/style.css"  with href="/css/style.css" to get a root relative path.

Answer (score 0):

You should first load your styles to Digital Ocean and link to them.
Here - `href="css/style.css"` - you use local path, which you have to replace with a URL of file on virtual machine.